# adding methods dynamically

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, objective-c-runtime

I am trying this method found in [Obj-c runtime reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html)

```
BOOL class_addMethod(Class cls, SEL name, IMP imp, const char *types)
```

I want to add a new method like:

```
- [AClass drawWithFrame:(NSRect)rect inView:(id)view]
```

So far I have written a C function:

```
void drawWithFrameInView(id this, SEL this_cmd, NSRect frame, id view){
...
}
```

now I am ready to do:

```
BOOL success = class_addMethod(NSClassFromString(@"AClass"), 
                               @selector(drawWithFrame:inView:), 
                               (IMP)drawWithFrameInView, 
                               "v@:@:@:");
```

but `success` is never YES, I have tried the same approach with methods with simpler signatures and it worked. So I think the problem is last parameter: `"v@:@:@:"`

What should I pass in this case to get my new method working ?

Comment: Why not name the first two arguments `self` and `_cmd`, so you can write the same code you would have written in a method?

Comment: Hummm ... just for an aesthetic reason. From the C point of view `self` and `_cmd` are supposed to be normal parameters. I didn't like the fact that a parameter was colored as keywords in Obj-C (even though they represent those keywords). That is all :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This will work:

```
char *types = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"v@:%s@", @encode(NSRect)] UTF8String];

BOOL success = class_addMethod(NSClassFromString(@"MyClass"), 
                               @selector(drawWithFrame:inView:), 
                               (IMP)drawWithFrameInView, 
                               types);
```

The reason why your code doesn't work is because `NSRect` is ***not an object***, it is a `typedef` to a `struct`.

Learn more about type encodings [**here**](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjCRuntimeGuide/Articles/ocrtTypeEncodings.html).

Comment: That seems to work (at least I got success = YES :) ). However the docs says: *Since the function must take at least two arguments—self and _cmd, the second and third characters must be “@:” (the first character is the return type)* and `types` does not contain a return type, is this because is `void` or there is some kind of inference here?

Comment: @nacho4d `types` ***does*** contain a return type - the first element is `'v'`, for `void`.

Comment: I'm disappointed that `@encode(…)` isn't considered a literal. If it were, you could concatenate them at compile time: `static const char types[] = @encode(void) @encode(id) @encode(SEL) @encode(NSRect) @encode(id);`

Comment: @Peter Agreed - even better would be if `@encode` were a variadic function: `@encode(void, id, SEL, NSRect, id);`

Comment: @Peter that sounds like a great feature request... :)